# Find Coordinates for boundary of an arbitrary city

Tags: php, postgis, wan

This is my first post on Stack Overflow. I am currently working on an app that mainly focuses on Geo clustering. I want to get the boundary coordinates of any arbitrary city (not only in US), so that when a new user logs in he/she may be added to the cluster based on the city to which he/she belongs.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim and Open Street Map.

Answer (score 1):

Get the address of the location using the google maps api or get the city by using postal code from the address

> https://developers.google.com/maps/